# Using a PS4 controller inverts the screen (17.10)

Tags: input-devices, libinput

Weird bug. The PS4 controller has a touchpad (which Ubuntu recognizes as a mousepad or something). When clicked, the screen is inverted (up is down, down is up). My guess is that this bug might be due to Wayland or libinput or something.

Thoughts?

Comment: Same for me. Were you able to connect the controller in a xorg session?With wayland it flips the screen and with xorg I'm not able to connect the controller via Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely the gyro in the PS4 controller that Ubuntu is recognizing, thinking its a tablet/laptop with sensors. Try flipping the controller over and locking the rotation (system tray > lock rotation).

Comment: Good explanation. What a fun bug.