# Dualshock 4 rotates my screen

Tags: screen, 17.10, gamepad

Every time I connect dualshock 4 to my laptop it turns my screen. When I rotate my dualshock, my screen rotates too. 
How to stop it?

I tried to use `ds4drv` but it helps only sometimes.

Comment: I also have this issue. It happens on my Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition (1 screen, Intel CPU/GPU) but not on my desktop (2 screens, AMD CPU / Nvidia GPU). It did not occur when I ran Ubuntu 16.04 on my XPS 13 with Unity. Probably a GNOME or Intel driver issue.

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/967424/using-a-ps4-controller-inverts-the-screen-17-10 . The answer there fixes it for me.

Comment: @awenger, thanks a lot. I found there an answer